# Why do some cases of Unity's Debug.Log() not work?

Tags: unity-game-engine, debugging, console

**In short:**
Somewhere in my game's code I use Debug.Log to show the length of a list, and display a helpful debug message. For some reason only the length of the list is shown, for no apparent reason.

**More details:**
This is my code:

```
    public override void UpdateTurn()
    {
        states.Add(currentState);
        Debug.Log(states.Count);
        Debug.Log("Hello");
```

(There is more to this function, but I don't believe it is relevant).

This method belongs to a class, "CannonScript", which inherits from "BreakableScript" which inherits from "TurnBasedObjectScript".
When pressing a UI Button, an object called the "TurnManager" loops over all "TurnBasedObjectScript"s in the game and calls this function ("UpdateTurn()").

My Problem:

- When I first press the button, I get the output "1" and "Hello".
- When I press it a second time, I get the output "2". **Without "Hello."**

This makes no sense.

As you can see there are no conditionals in the code or anything that might change the flow. And yet, the Log(states.Count) works and the other one doesn't.

I tried:

- Changing the order. Still got only the one that prints states.Count.
- I tried printing other types (maybe the problem is that I'm printing a string, for some reason...?) but no.
- However when I print (states.Count + " aaa") it does show up in the console everytime.
- Restarting Unity, removing and re-adding the script to the GameObject... Nothing changed.

I have no idea what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have collapse function enabled on your console, that makes so that the same messages isn't printed multiple times. Disabling it should solve the problem

Comment: This is exactly it. Thank you so much, I got so confused :D