# Why Is ReadLine() Skipping certain lines

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, readline

Overarching plan, make a cyoa game. Things have been working great for a while. But then errors I can't understand have been occuring. Debug.Log() print statements not working or skipping for some reason, but data still be used properly at times.I decided to scrap and start again just to make sure I'm reading my graph data correctly. Below I'll attach the data I'm trying to read, the code I'm using to read it, and what the Debug console is outputting. I'm running this in Unity with C#. I'm sorry if this is stupid or has been answered elsewhere, I'm not fully getting what's wrong. I suspect it might be invisible endline characters, but then I don't even know how to fix that.

The Graph Data I'm reading in

```
0 id    
{The following questions will help determine ...
Personal Power
> What you know
> Who you know
> What you have
> Who you are
> ( skip ) I know my House Arcana...
No Info 
1 id
1 id 
Mind + 2 Strength - 1 Sneakiness - 1 Heart - 1 endline 
No Info 
id 1 id
Mind - 1 Strength - 1 Sneakiness - 1 Heart + 2 endline 
No Info 
1 id 
Mind - 1 Strength - 1 Sneakiness + 2 Heart - 1 endline 
No Info 
1 id 
Mind - 1 Strength + 2 Sneakiness - 1 Heart - 1 endline 
No Info 
3 id 
No Info 
No Info
```

The above is all the data of a Node in the structure I made, not even getting sent or used anywhere at this point.

The code below is what I'm using to read and parse the information. The filepath is correct and that all works. It gets the majority of the data, just not all of it

```
string line;
        //c1s.text = "it gets to this at all"; - this worked so it does get here.
        string filepath = "Assets/Resources/GraphData.txt"; 
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filepath))
            {
                //int i = 0;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != "endgame")
                {
                    
                    Debug.Log(line);
                }
                sr.Close();
            }
            
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The File could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

Finally here is the output from the debug.log

```
0 id    
{The following questions will help determine ...
Personal Power
> What you know
> Who you know
> What you have
> Who you are
> ( skip ) I know my House Arcana...
No Info 
1 id
1 id 
Mind + 2 Strength - 1 Sneakiness - 1 Heart - 1 endline 
Mind - 1 Strength - 1 Sneakiness - 1 Heart + 2 endline  
Mind - 1 Strength - 1 Sneakiness + 2 Heart - 1 endline 
Mind - 1 Strength + 2 Sneakiness - 1 Heart - 1 endline  
3 id
```

I've been changing the format, adding and removing spaces at the ends of lines, deleting and rewriting lines, the output always changes somewhat but it's never consistent, or even close to all of the above. I can't for the life of me get what's causing some lines to be read and some skipped. Even adding "endline" to the end of some of those lines has been inconsistent. Sometimes I can see one or two lines that aren't there, but it varies, and they aren't even the ones I edit necessarily.

Comment: and the count numbers at the right dont go up?

Comment: The only problem I see with your `StreamReader` code is that you need to check to see whether you reached the end of the stream by checking `&& line != null`.  Absent that, if `endgame` is missing from the file, you have an infinite loop.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/rNDV6W.

Comment: I'm not a Unity developer, but could it be that `Debug.Log()` isn't working as expected?  See [Print/Debug.Log is not showing output on Unity Console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42338376) or [Console not outputting from Debug.Log()](https://discussions.unity.com/t/console-not-outputting-from-debug-log/112024) or [Why do some cases of Unity's Debug.Log() not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65321572) or [Debug.Log()/Print()/UnityEngine.Debug.Log() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71559960) for cases I found where this happened in the past.

Comment: Rather than depending on visual inspection tools like `Debug.Log()` to verify the correctness of your code, consider using [unit testing](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/testing-editortestsrunner.html) to verify correctness, e.g. like so: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q7vUc4

Comment: Reason for my question is that is a set of the unique output. I bet at the end the lines that have been repeated get little numbers. Because you have the console set to do so

Comment: For instance don't use `Console.WriteLine` this will not show up .. rather use `Debug.LogException`. And then as mentioned check the `Collapse` function in the Unity console, make sure you don't have any filters (log message type or string search) enabled

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code on my local and it works fine, I suspect that your debugger doesn't really log the line properly due to some configurations on your end. Try use Console.WriteLine and see the result directly from the console.

```
string line;
string filepath = "./GraphData.txt";
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("start");
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filepath))
    {
        //int i = 0;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != "endgame")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("end");
        Console.ReadLine();
        sr.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The File could not be read:");
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

[image]